# How to use entity framework function to find certain cell

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table named product having product id, product bill id and.. the bill id is passed to my controller as a parameter.

I can use the entities from framework and find all rows with product id using
db.tbl_product.Find(product id).

But now i need to find all transactions using bill id. How do I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tbl_product is a `DbSet<Product>` or something similar, you should be able to use LINQ to query the `DbSet`.  To find a single item with a specific BillId property value, you would do something like this:

```
var product = db.tbl_product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BillId == billId);
```

If there were multiple products with the same BillId, you could do the following:

```
var products = db.tbl_product.Where(p => p.BillId == billId);
```

It largely depends on the schema of the table and how you're using Entity Framework.  I would highly recommend reading a book or tutorial on Entity Framework.  There are lots of them out there, for example: [Entity Framework Tutorial](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.aspx).